# Span within a sentence with jade

Tags: pug

How would I be able to do this with Jade?

```
<h3 class = "blurb"> how would I <span>do this</span></h3>
```

I can do pretty much everything but introducing a span mid sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should help you:

```
h3
    how should I
    span do this
```

Your output code will not be exactly what you want, but when it's rendered in html, it should be what you need

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm fairly new to using jade and thought that by doing that the compiler would just read the span as text.

Comment: If you see in an output you'll see that `how` is compiled as an element. Like this: `<h3><how>Should I</how><span>do this</span></h3>` You need `|` before how.

Comment: How to do the same if span comes initial?   `<h3 class = "blurb">  how <span> would I </span> do this</h3>`

Answer (score 3):

```
h3.blur.
 how would I <span>do this</span>
```

OR

```
h3.blur
  | how would I 
  span do this
```

Please note that copying above snippet may not work because of the indentation. You need to convert spaces to tabs in sublime or similar editor.

Answer (score 2):

The pipe is also optional depending on the context

```
h3.blurb how would i
 span do this
```

also works

Answer (score 0):

May be the proper way to do it is to use [pug's tag interpolation](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html#tag-interpolation):

```
h3.blur how would I #[span do this]
```