# How to set some words of a sentence bold / strong with pug?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug, jade4j

I use pug as a templating engine.

I'm able to load content on my page. Following some snippets of my code:

#### server.js

```
routing.get('/introduction', (req, resp) => {

    loadContent( function(err, content){

        if(content){
            resp.render('intro_page', content);
        }
    });
});


function loadContent( cb ){
    const cont = {
        explanation: ['Word three of paragraph one shall be bold. ', 'Words one and five of paragraph 2 shall be bold.', 'Words one up to four of paragraph 3 shall be bold.', 'and so on'],
    };

    return cb(null, cont);
}
```

#### intro_page.pug

```
div
    each paragraph in explanation
        div= paragraph
```

#### wished result

Word three **of** paragraph one shall be bold.

**Words** one and five **of** paragraph 2 shall be bold.

**Words one up to** four of paragraph 3 shall be bold.

and so on

Is there a way with the pug and my approach to set arbitrarily selected words bold? My online search stilled without result. How can I do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36613183/6066986

Answer (score 1):

I have found my working solution. To whom it my concern:

#### server.js

```
routing.get('/introduction', (req, resp) => {

    loadContent( function(err, content){

        if(content){
            resp.render('intro_page', content);
        }
    });
});


function loadContent( cb ){
    const bo = '<span style="font-weight: bold">';
    const bc = '</span>';
    const bk = '<br/><br/>';
    const cont = {
        explanation: [`Word three ${bo} of ${bc} paragraph one shall be bold. ${bo} Words ${bc} one and five ${bo} of ${bc} paragraph 2 shall be bold. ${bo} Words one up to ${bc} four of paragraph 3 shall be bold. ${bk} and so on`],
    };

    return cb(null, cont);
}
```

Important are the `. Not to be confused with '. Template literals only work with [back ticks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

#### intro_page.pug

```
div
    div= !{explanation}
```